# 'RKManagedObjectRequestOperation' for class message is a forward declaration

Tags: ios, core-data, ios9, restkit

I decided to ask the question here as it has been days I have been looking for a solution.

I just integrated RestKit to my project via CocoaPods. I am on iOS 9 with ElCapitan and the last version of XCode (7.2)
Everything worked fine until the build step in XCode.

I got the following error among others

> Receiver 'RKManagedObjectRequestOperation' for class message is a forward declaration

Please see below the code that generates the error :
[Code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovmmT.png)

```
RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
operation.managedObjectContext = managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
operation.managedObjectCache = managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache;
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
    //Product *product = [result firstObject];
```

However, I think I correctly imported the library RestKit/CoreData :
[I declared RestKit/CoreData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGYw6.png)

And also in the prefix header:

```
#import <Availability.h>

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED

    #ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
    #warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
    #endif

    #ifdef __OBJC__
        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
        #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        #import <RestKit/CoreData.h>
        #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
        #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
    #endif

    #else
        #ifdef __OBJC__
        #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
        #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
        #import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
    #endif

#endif
```

I would like to request your help on this issue.
"Receiver type 'RKManagedObjectRequestOperation' for instance message is a forward declaration."

Is there something I should check in the build settings etc?

Answer (score 0):

RKManagedObjectRequestOperation is not under the CoreData.h header file, but rather the Network.h header file, so I would include in your list:

Comment: Thanks! In fact it is better now! Grazie Mille